# how to make materializecss center navbar?

Tags: css, html, materialize

I want to make my menu's center on the navbar using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com)

My HTML code:

```
<div class="navbar-utility theme">
  <ul class="right">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="navbar-search-trigger">
        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
      </a>
     </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#" id="navbar-full-screen">
        <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt tiny"></i>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">
        Dropdown
        <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
      </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS code is below:

```
.navbar-utility{
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 64px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-utility ul.right{

  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin:0px auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why use class `right` if you don't want it to be floated to the right?

Comment: i want to making navbar menu center on mobile device and right on large device. I was fix it using [THIS TRICK](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support)

Answer (score 0):

You just try this code..

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Tab one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Tab two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab four</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

#menu {
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   background:#fff;
   border-bottom:4px solid #000;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}
#menu ul {
   clear:left;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
   text-align:center;
}
#menu ul li {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   right:50%;
}
#menu ul li a {
   display:block;
   margin:0 0 0 1px;
   padding:3px 10px;
   background:#ddd;
   color:#000;
   text-decoration:none;
   line-height:1.3em;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
   background:#369;
   color:#fff;
}
#menu ul li a.active,
#menu ul li a.active:hover {
   color:#fff;
   background:#000;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```